# How are printing jobs scheduled between users?

Tags: drivers, printing, cups

I was how printing jobs are scheduled when multiple users/computers share a remote printer? Is it first come first served, based on user specific priority, based on the time need to transfer data from computer to printer?

What do the drivers and applications in Linux handle the scheduling?

What do the printers do about scheduling then?

I remember seeing the topic somewhere, but I can't find it any more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Jobs can be assigned a priority by the `lp` command using `-o job-priority` or `-q`.  The default is usually 50, but can be set using `lpoptions` for each user.  Jobs with the highest numbered priority are handled first, then the next number down and so forth.  Range is 1-100.

When jobs of the same priority are to be printed they are usually done on a first come, first served basis.  However if the scheduler sees a mime type it will print them in alphabetical order of the mime types (`text/bar` prints before `text/foo`), unless there is a file called `/etc/cups/mime.types`  If this file exists, then it is consulted for the priority, which can be assigned to mime types.

See `lp(1)` and `mime.types(5)` for more details.

Comment: Thanks. are printing requests based on the time need to transfer data from computer to printer?

What do the drivers and applications in Linux handle the scheduling?

What do the printers do about scheduling then?

Comment: As far as I am aware neither applications nor drivers do any scheduling.  Within a single computer `cups` will handle things using priorities.  A networked printer may have some scheduling, you would need to investigate the printer-specific documentation.  I can't find anything in my main printer (HP colour laser), so I assume the first machine to contact the printer will grab control until the job has been completed.  As regards transfer time, I would guess not, it is so dependent upon network factors.

Comment: If you really need to control scheduling, you can always serve the printer to other computers from a single computer.